# Displaying an ASP.net application on a different site

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I have an ASP.net application and a website (wordpress) that is hosted on different servers.  What I want to do is to display the asp.net site/app on the other website.  What would be the best way to do this? Using an HTML iframe was suggested to me.  Are there any other alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

iframe is the way you want to do it